# Changing APIs in run-time or compile-time?

Tags: c++

I'm coding a game engine class and I've been suggested to add this #define to deal with multiple APIs in this manner:

```
#ifdef OGL
    typedef COpenGl CBaseApi;
#elif defined( OGLES )
    typedef COpenGlEs CBaseApi;
#elif defined( DX9 )
    typedef CDirectX9 CBaseApi;
#elif defined( DX10 )
    typedef CDirectX10 CBaseApi;
#elif defined( DX11 )
    typedef CDirectX11 CBaseApi;
#endif
```

And I have two questions: How can I get the above to work?

I tried:

```
class CBaseAPI
{
    //abstract class, virtual functions
} 
class COpenGL : public CBaseAPI
{
    //implementations
}
```

But it didn't work as I expected.

And the second question is, is this #define method better than using a factory of some sort? I was initially doing this:

```
//inside the Main program
myGameEngine.Initialize(GraphicAPI::DirectX11);

//inside the Initialize function
void GameEngine::Initialize(GraphicAPI graphicAPI)
{
    switch(graphicAPI)
    {
        case GraphicAPI::DirectX11:
        {
            //Defined as private members:                
            //BaseAPI graphicAPI;

            //class CDirectX11 : public BaseAPI

            graphicAPI = new CDirectX11(); 
        }
        //other cases here
    }
}
```

Are there any pros and cons to these methods, and what is the preferred one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second one is terrible. Two-phase initialization is very error prone, and in the general case, there is absolutely no need whatsoever for your game to change rendering APIs at run-time. It's a complete waste of time and performance to use interfaces and inheritance, not to mention a loss of nice strong typing.

For the #define, there is no need for the classes to be linked by inheritance. You might do better with a template, but conditional compilation is what the preprocessor was made for. Simple usage scenario:

```
class OGL {
public:
    void dostuff();
};
class DX {
public:
    void dostuff();
};
class GameEngine {
#ifdef USE_OPENGL
    OGL BaseAPI;
#else
    DX BaseAPI;
#endif
public:
    void dostuff() { BaseAPI.dostuff(); }
};
```

Also, CClass? Owch. You need to find new learning materials, buddy.

Comment: So you would have to recompile to change rendering APIs?

Comment: @Hna being able to change rendering API at runtime is not worth the extra performance cost.

Comment: @Borgleader Well not change it at runtime. More like read a command line argument or a users settings file then choose the rendering API. You can't do that with preprocessor-directives.

Comment: @Borgleader What exactly is the performance cost? I don't see it.

Comment: @Hna By not knowing the concrete type of the API at compile time you lose any chance of inlining for one thing.

Comment: @Hna: Stronger types means that the compiler can perform many more optimizations, with inlining being one of the most potent examples. Another example is that the interface can be expressed in strong types itself, whereas a run-time interface can only return other run-time interfaces.

Comment: -1 Generally speaking _"The second one is terrible"_ is terrible. Many games are able to change their rendering systems or graphic engines at run-time (by setting files or command-line switches) and it's a good ability to support wide area of systems.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typedef with the same name as a base class (CBaseApi). That won't fare well.

Did you mean something like:

```
class CBaseAPI
{
    //abstract class, virtual functions
};
class COpenGlEs : public CBaseAPI
{
    // implementations  
};

#ifdef OGL
    typedef COpenGl BaseApiImpl;
#elif defined( OGLES )
    typedef COpenGlEs BaseApiImpl;
#elif defined( DX9 )
    typedef CDirectX9 BaseApiImpl;
#elif defined( DX10 )
    typedef CDirectX10 BaseApiImpl;
#elif defined( DX11 )
    typedef CDirectX11 BaseApiImpl;
#endif
```